# Angular routing not working when deployed statically with Node

Tags: node.js, angular

I am building my angular project and inserting the build output into a public folder in the root of my node project.

In my app.js file, I have the following code:

```
...
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
...
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
     res.send(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
```

When deploying the project, this works perfectly; when I load the page, the index.html is rendered and navigating through the page works.

However, when I enter a url like for example '/admin', which is defined in my angular routing, I get a not found error.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the .send() method... 
I replaced this:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.send(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
```

with this:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
```

and it worked. 
Sorry guys for making you loose time. You helped me research different things though!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve ur issue
Create .htaccess file in root folder and pass

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: I've seen this solution with some differences.

Comment: Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]

Comment: What exactly does this do? Haven't tried it yet, will do now.

Comment: .htaccess is a configuration file for use on web servers running the Apache Web Server software. .htaccess files can be used to alter the configuration of the Apache Web Server software to enable/disable additional functionality and features that the Apache Web Server software has to offer. These facilities include basic redirect functionality, for instance if a 404 file not found error occurs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code but

1. you can try setting up the base-href in your index.html

   ```
   <base href="/">
   ```

   properly....
2. Serving with nginx could have a configuration like this. It directs the index.html to the correct routes of your SPA:

   ```
   root /home/app/dist/;

   server {
       listen 8080;
       server_name  localhost;

       location /admin/ {
         alias /home/app/dist/my-app/admin/;
         expires -1;
         add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalicate, post-check=0 pre-check=0";
         index index.html;
         try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;
       }

       location / {
         alias /home/app/dist/my-app/;
         expires -1;
         add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalicate, post-check=0 pre-check=0";
         index index.html;
         try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;
       }
   }
   ```

see nginx how-to here: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-properly-get-angular-and-nginx-working-together-for-development-3e5d158734bf

Answer (score 0):

above router.get, you should have :-

```
// serve angular front end files from root path
router.use('/', express.static('public', { redirect: false }));
```